# /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, wine, dpkg, playonlinux

I have Ubuntu 14.04, and I'm trying to install wine:i386 to use PlayOnLinux, following [this article](http://wiki.playonlinux.com/index.php/Installing_PlayOnLinux). However, when I run:

`sudo echo "foreign-i386 architecture"> /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch`

I get this error `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch: Permission denied`

Being still new to Ubuntu I don't know how safe it is (or advisable) to manually change permissions to overcome this. What should I do to solve this?

**EDIT**
The main objective of this question is to install Wine, not the syntax itself (although the syntax was the problem), the accepted answer provided a better way of solving this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems:

- `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch` file is being opened by the shell as unprivileged user before the `echo` command runs, hence the permission error as only `root` should be able to create the file or write in it. The `sudo` is only being applied to `echo` command.
- The string `foreign-i386 architecture` is not correct for enabling multiarch support for `i386` architecture, the correct string is `foreign-architecture i386`.

To fix these, you can do:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "foreign-architecture i386" >>/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch'
```

Or

```
echo "foreign-architecture i386" | sudo tee -a /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch
```

---

Note that, the easiest way to enable multiarch and add `i386` architecture would be:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

---

Don't forget to run `sudo apt-get update` after enabling multiarch.